# Google sheet - custom timestamp script doesn't work on Andriod

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp, google-sheets-api

When the user check the checkbox, the last modified date appears in the next column, this is my sheet.

But the add timestamp function it's not working when I try on phone and tablet.

I know some triggers don't work with G sheets in Android like active or getactive. Please help to me, how can I fix this problem. Thank you!

Here is the code (from internetgeeks...):

Screenshot of the script:

[image]

Comment: This issue is not reproducible. Please consider providing a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on, as well as providing the code in text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

welcome, it would be fine to get the code in text. Nevertheless, this one works fine on my android phone

```
function onEdit(event){ 
  var col = 1; // colonne A
  var feuille = "Feuille 1";
  var f = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
  if ((r.getColumn() == col) && (f.getName() == feuille) && (r.getRow() > 2)){ 
    var d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "EEE dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm") // H24
    r.offset(0,1).setValue(d);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It's not working for me, but I tested again and again the sheet, and seem like the chekcbox is the problem. If I type any character in the empty cell, the script works well. With using the checkbox... don't.

Comment: It's a bit difficult sometimes to activate a checkbox within a phone. I have tried it again and it works fine for me either with text and textbox. Here is a sample test https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q3Nm7QLPhQxW1ceEJNtdSgbkX9Qkg_aUf2E-ugNbQ-8/edit?usp=sharing (available 1 day)